# Write elements of matrix into vector using OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am rather new with OpenMP. I want to write all elements of a big matrix into a vector using OpenMP threading to speed things up.

In my serial code I am simply doing the following:

```
m=1
DO k=1,n_lorentz
   DO i=1,n_channels 
     DO p=1,n_lorentz
          DO j=1,n_channels
           vector(m) = Omega(j,p,i,k)
           m=m+1
       END DO
     END DO
   END DO 
END DO
```

Now I'd like to use an OMP loop to write the elements of Omega into vector in a parallel fashion:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(k,i,p,j)
  ! bla bla 
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

The question is how to keep track of the current vector index, since in this case the `m` parameter from the serial code will be incremented by different threads, resulting in a total mess.

Answer (score 4):

One answer is: you don't need to keep track of `m`. Instead, analyzing the loop, we find that:

- Every time `j` increases by one, `m` increases by one;
- Every time `p` increases by one, `m` increases by `n_channels`;
- Every time `i` increases by one, `m` increases by `n_channels*n_lorentz`;
- Every time `k` increases by one, `m` increases by `n_channels*n_lorentz*n_channels`.

From these observations, you can write an explicit expression for `m`:

```
m = j + n_channels*((p-1) + n_lorentz*((i-1) + n_channels*(k-1)))
```

Being able to explicitly calculate the index should solve your problem :).

Comment: Thanks!! This does the job indeed :)